# angular data not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a login form that I trying to collect data from to send to my api, the html looks a little like this,

```
<form novalidate ng-controller="loginController" ng-submit="doLogin()">  
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="formData.username">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formData.password">
</form>
```

my login controller looks like this,

```
var app = app || {};
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $routeParams, authentication) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.doLogin = function(form) {
        //authentication.authenticate();
        console.log($scope.formData);
    }
});
```

the doLogin function runs on form submit but `$scope.formData` is empty, I would expect to have a username and a password attribute?

Comment: can you make a plunker or jfiddle? I think we may need to see more code.

Comment: Your code works, only username need to be valid for the show in the scope. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10323/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are making username type="email" and html5 validates with a regex pattern, that the value entered must be valid like: "alex@h.com" here I attach an example on code pen: http://codepen.io/alex06/pen/NRvXNm
and also info about this in angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

```
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .controller('loginController', function($scope) {
    $scope.formData;

    $scope.doLogin = function(form) {
        //authentication.authenticate();
        console.log($scope.formData);
    }
});




  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <form novalidate ng-controller="loginController" ng-submit="doLogin()" name="myForm">  
         <input type="email" name="emailInput" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="formData.username">
      <span style="color: red;" ng-show="myForm.emailInput.$error.email">error</span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formData.password">
         <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
```